# NetBeans8 - Symlink content marked as new when commiting even with svn-special

Tags: svn, netbeans-8

I have a project with a symlink to a folder :
/cache/search -> /my/other/folder

In order to make its content ignored by SVN, I put a ***svn-special:**** property on this symlink. This trick works with Eclipse & Subclipse but NetBeans8 always marks the content as "new".

I also tried to add ***svn-ignore:search/**** to the parent folder without any result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you realize how to solve this problem? I am facing the same for almost a month...

Comment: I found an other solution with chown (I'm on Linux). I changed the user of my folder for www-data so apache2 can see my files but not my IDE. It's dirty but it's working!

Comment: Hmm, clever! But under which user does the NB run? Isn't it your user? So even you do not see the folder anymore, right? I found one *clean* solution in NB - mark all the folders and files under the symlink file and click with RMB on them - navigate to Subversion -> Ignore and select **Exclude from commit**. It's also only a kind of workaround since when you want to commit you still see all the symlinked folders and files but they are already unchecked and won't be committed. But your solution is much better as with it the files won't be present at all!

Comment: Anyway, I reopened an [already fixed NB issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231588) and there seems to be a new setting you can put into your config file, though it's not working for me... Maybe you could try it and provide your result here...

Comment: NB is running under my user so it doesn't see content of my folder. **Exclude from commit** is also possible but my content is regulary regenerated... I also tried the **-J-Dversioning.subversion.doNotFollowSymlinks=true** option in netbeans.conf and NB continues to mark my content as "new"...

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with that switch. If you could contribute in the issue maybe they'll see it's not only my problem.

Comment: The problem is fixed - the problem was I put the switch at wrong place. In the `netbeans.conf` file there is the property `netbeans_default_options`, which is a string. This switch has to be inserted as a part of the value separated by space from the previous options. Restart the IDE and enjoy!

Comment: `netbeans_default_options` was already configured but I change the command of my launcher with `netbeans -J-Dversioning.subversion.doNotFollowSymlinks=true`. It's working but extremly slow! Finally, I'll keep my solution in order to commit fast. Thanks a lot for your help!